# Vue JS - Checkbox / if Checked do This if unchecked do that

Tags: html, vue.js, checkbox

im trying to create a checkbox that runs one function when it is initaly checked and runs another when it is then unchecked.

here something ive tryied out
theres also a variable that already has been read out and represents the current status

```
   <input type="checkbox" :checked="e.Processed == true" v-model="toggle" true-value= functionTrue false-value="no">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506235/vuejs-click-event-from-checkbox/50506564

Answer (score 4):

Just register an `@change` handler.

```js
   const onChange = (event) => {
       // handle logic
   }
```

```html
   <input type="checkbox" :checked="e.Processed == true" v-model="toggle" true-value= functionTrue false-value="no" @change="onChange($event)">
```

Comment: But how do i know the current status?... I would need some kind of logic in the onChange to check what status is present now ... right?

Comment: `event.target.checked`

Answer (score 1):

How i solved it

for the input type

```
  <input type="checkbox"  :checked="e.Processed === true" @change="onChangeProcessed($event,e)">
```

the function checks whats the current state

```
          onChangeProcessed(e,d) {
           if (e.target.checked == true) {
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log("ACTIVE");
                    console.log(d);
                    console.log(e.target.checked);
                    this.markReady(d);
                    
                    
            };
          if (e.target.checked == false ) {
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log("OFF");
                    console.log(d);
                    console.log(e.target.checked);
                    this.markNotReady(d);

               /*       console.log(e.target.value);
                    this.markNotReady(d) */
            }
},
```